# How can I share a variable from MainActivity to a fragment?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

I want to share variable : master between MainActivity to ListAdapter. Can you tell me how to do it ? I tried with bundles and a lot of things, but in the end I received errors.

Main Activity

```
package com.example.roomapp

import android.content.Intent
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.navigation.findNavController
import androidx.navigation.ui.setupActionBarWithNavController
import com.example.roomapp.AESKnowledgeFcatory.decrypt
import com.example.roomapp.HashUtils.sha256
import com.example.roomapp.fragments.add.AddFragment
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activitycreate.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activitylogin.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.custom_row.*
import kotlin.properties.ReadOnlyProperty
import kotlin.reflect.KProperty

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    var master: String = "0"
    var checkLogin2: String = ""
    var lf_ch = false


    fun createMaster(v:View){
        this.master = this.editmasterpass.text.toString()

        val sharedPref = this.getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE) ?:return
        with (sharedPref.edit()){
            putString("cheie",sha256(master))
            commit()
        }

        val sharedPref2 = this.getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE) ?: return
        val defaultValue = sharedPref2.getString("cheie", "ABA")
        System.out.println(" Key value = " + defaultValue)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }

    fun checklogin(v: View)
    {
        this.checkLogin2 = this.editTextTextPassword.text.toString()
        val castoras = this.getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE)
        val defaultValue2 = castoras.getString("cheie", "ABA")
        if(sha256(this.checkLogin2)==defaultValue2.toString())
        {
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        }
        else {
            textView3.text="Incorrect Password"
        }
    }


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        val castoras = this.getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE)
        val defaultValue2 = castoras.getString("cheie", "key not found")

        System.out.println("Abracanabra= "+defaultValue2.toString())

        if ((defaultValue2.toString())=="key not found") {
            setContentView(R.layout.activitycreate)
        }
        else {
            setContentView((R.layout.activitylogin))
        }



    }

    override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
        val navController = findNavController(R.id.fragment)
        return navController.navigateUp() || super.onSupportNavigateUp()
    }

    // cum sa pasam variabila master

    

}
```

ListAdapter

```
package com.example.roomapp.fragments.list
import android.app.PendingIntent.getActivity
import android.content.Context
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.example.roomapp.AESKnowledgeFcatory.encrypt
import com.example.roomapp.R
import com.example.roomapp.data.User
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.custom_row.view.*
import android.content.SharedPreferences
import com.example.roomapp.MainActivity


class ListAdapter: RecyclerView.Adapter<ListAdapter.MyViewHolder>() {

    private var userList = emptyList<User>()


    class MyViewHolder(itemView: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {}

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {
        return MyViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.custom_row, parent, false))
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
       return userList.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val currentItem = userList[position]
        holder.itemView.id_txt.text = currentItem.id.toString()
        holder.itemView.firstName_txt.text = currentItem.firstName
// I want to use the master string here, master+currentItem.salt 
        

holder.itemView.lastName_txt.text = encrypt(currentItem.lastName,currentItem.salt)
        holder.itemView.salt_txt.text = currentItem.salt
    }

    fun setData(user: List<User>){
        this.userList = user
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
}
```

I need a method that can pass me the "master" variable to ListAdapter, because I need to pass certain informations.
List fragment

```
package com.example.roomapp.fragments.list

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.lifecycle.Observer
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider
import androidx.navigation.fragment.findNavController
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import com.example.roomapp.R
import com.example.roomapp.data.UserViewModel
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_list.view.*

class ListFragment() : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var mUserViewModel: UserViewModel

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list, container, false)

        // Recyclerview
        val adapter = ListAdapter()
        val recyclerView = view.recyclerview
        recyclerView.adapter = adapter
        recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(requireContext())

        // UserViewModel
        mUserViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(UserViewModel::class.java)
        mUserViewModel.readAllData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { user ->
            adapter.setData(user)
        })

        view.floatingActionButton.setOnClickListener {
            findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_listFragment_to_addFragment)
        }

        return view
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add a constructor parameter in your `ListAdapter` and pass the value of master string when creating the `ListAdapter`  in `MainActivity`, this can be done as

```
class ListAdapter(private val master: String): 
                  RecyclerView.Adapter<ListAdapter.MyViewHolder>()
```

and in your `MainActivity`, where you create object of `ListAdapter`, pass the value of master

```
listAdapter = ListAdapter(master)
```

Now you can use master in your `ListAdapter` as you like

Comment: (28, 35): No value passed for parameter 'master'

In ListFragment 



val adapter = ListAdapter()

Comment: use `val adapter = ListAdapter(master)`

Comment: Unresolved reference: master

And if I try to do the same thing as with ListAdapter My app will not work.

Comment: in which file are you writing this line?

Comment: and how exactly you load the `ListFragment`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236152/discussion-between-criss-barbu-and-mightywoz).